# Shutting down a Python program using PyQt and PyGame.music()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pygame, pyqt4

I've been working on a media player in python that uses pygame.mixer to play music and PyQt4 to build the UI.

I'm currently using a while loop to check if a song is finished so the next song can be loaded in from the queue. In order to make sure that the user can still interact with the PyQt buttons while the while loop is running, I have put **QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()** into the while loop.

However, now when I close the main window while music is playing, the program does not stop (as it normally does) and the music keeps playing. 
The program also can't detect the **app.aboutToQuit.connect**() command while the music is playing (meaning it can when music isn't playing).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, obviously you need to add a conditional statement to break out of the loop when appropriate.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes I have thought about this but I'm not sure what the condition you could use to break out of it. I've tried some research on this site and in the documentation. It is possible that I have overlooked something obvious though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this issue a while ago so thought I should put it here for anyone else.

I gave the program an internal exit button in the ui, then made the button call **os._exit(0)**. It worked perfectly then.

Checking the Python and PyQt documentation gave no comment on closing a application window while a while loop is being performed.

Any other solutions would be appreciated though.